# Force freetype to recognize cross-compile

Tags: cross-compiling, configure, autoconf, freetype

I try to cross-compile *freetype*, but its *configure* / *autoconf*-cruft seems to fail. The configure output is:

```
cd builds/unix; /bin/sh ./configure  '--host=le32-unknown-nacl' 'CC_BUILD=/usr/bin/cc'
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... le32-unknown-nacl
checking for le32-unknown-nacl-gcc... /home/andreas/Projects/emscripten/emcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
```

Strange is that `build` and `host` are different, so I don't really understand, why it thinks it would not cross-compile. Does anyone know how to force the configure script to use cross-compiling?

Comment: How you configuring freetype?also for which target r u compiling?  can u share it so that i can figure out

Comment: Look at the first line. There is the exact command.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `docs/INSTALL.CROSS` file distributed with Freetype, you should use *both* the `--host=` **and** `--build=` options. I do not know if it will work, but it certainly is worth a try. I would also add `CC_BUILD` as you did.